# Suggestion for canonical question on hook_menu

Tags: discussion, canonical

Related to this discussion [Do we have "Canonical questions", on DA?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2168/do-we-have-canonical-questions-on-da).

I took some time out to write this fairly long answer Q/A: [How should I implement hook_menu()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62473/how-to-implement-hook-menu/62474#62474)

My hope is that the question can achieve two things. It's step by step nature, should be helpful for anyone with a "Why doesn't my hook_menu work?" question, of which there are quite a few. Secondly, it should cover a lot of other basic "How do I do X in hook_menu".

I suggest it be considered for canonization.

As is common on meta-sites, I suggest up votes on this question could be considered "Yes, canonize it", and down votes be considered "No, don't canonize it".

I would love to hear feedback on the style and scope of the question, as I may decide to write more potentially canonical questions if this gets accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The only suggestion I would give is to always prefix the function names with the short name of the module. For the rest, the question, and the answer are excellent.